# req.secure not working in Express 4

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, https

I want to force redirect all requests to `https` urls on my nodejs app, as my app responds to both `http` and `https` urls and when I scan it, it shows alerts for `http` urls.
I tried using code similar to this:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.secure || req.headers.host === "localhost:8080")
    {
        next();
    }
    else
    {
        res.redirect("https://" + req.headers.host + req.url);      
    }
});
```

Logically, it seems like this should work. But `req.secure` is always evaluating to false, even if I am hitting `https` url.
I tried using `app.set('trust proxy', true);`, but this did not help. I have removed this line now.

I am using nginx as proxy but I cannot make changes there. I need to implement this redirection through my code.

Thanks.

Comment: If you do have nginx in front of express, show it's config.

Comment: @AlexeyTen actually, I do not have access to that. I need to contact server admin for that and that would delay my work. I do not get https in `req.protocol` whether I use http or https. In last mail, server admin told me to implement redirection in code.

Comment: Well, without config we could only guess that nginx terminates ssl and always request your application via `http`. You should check if nginx sends additional headers to your app. Usually it's `x-forwarded-proto` header. BTW, it's common to do `http` to `https` redirect in nginx without even hitting an application.

Comment: @AlexeyTen thanks :) . I'll forward this to my server admin. Currently, I do not get `x-forwarded-proto` in my `req.header`.